# web2py - Adding fields to form when user clicks button

Tags: web2py

What I want to do is to show the user a set of fields every time the user clicks a button. I would like the new fields to be displayed below the already displayed fields. When the user clicks submit, I want to do operations on all the viewable fields. After completing these operations I will insert into my database. These extra fields are not database fields.

I am not sure how to add fields dynamically. I am not sure how I would reference the new fields. Can someone please show me an example so I may adopt it to my needs. I am using web2py so a solution that works in this framework would be great. Please let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is changing my database field to type:list. This gave me the ability to dynamically add fields on FORM pages. I also created my own validator class to check if the input for every 'type:list' instance was correct.